# Calling `ver` in FOR expression from a batch file freezes cmd in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I am trying to check OS version from a batch file and I am running into the following problem.

The line

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('ver') DO (SET var=%%i)
```

will freeze the cmd when executing from a batch file while the command `ver` by itself (in the same batch file) executes without problem. (`ver` has the following output.)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356]
```

What could be wrong in the expression?

Comment: What is the name of your batch file (perhaps `ver.bat`) ?

Comment: `alias.cmd`. It shouldn't be a name conflict since `ver` in the same file runs correctly. Right?

Comment: What happens if you open a Command Prompt window and enter `FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('ver') DO (SET var=%i)`?

Comment: BTW, as far as I know the `ver` command reports the version number of `cmd.exe`, not of Windows. Whilst this is unlikely to be different, it is possible. `Win32_OperatingSystem` will provide a more robust result.

Comment: @Compo It works when using in cmd directly. Re true meaning of `ver`, it does produce the correct version number and `ver` in batch file runs. So even if `ver` is associated with `cmd.exe`, I am baffled as to how `ver` would fail in the for loop + in batch file.

Comment: I don't have `Win32_OperatingSystem` btw.

Comment: I am unable to replicate your problem. What encoding are you saving the script as, what's the output of `ver`, and does `var` already have a value?

Comment: The script is saved to a .cmd file. It's intended to be run upon the start of `cmd.exe`. `var` does not have existing value.

Comment: No, I mean like ANSI, UTF-8, Windows-1251, etc.

Comment: @SomethingDark UTF-8

Comment: Try saving it as ANSI. Batch is sometimes weird about UTF-8.

Comment: Does the problem only occurs when you start it via registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`? Then it's caused by the fact, that `FOR /F` will also start a new cmd instance

Comment: @Compo: Are single quotes required around `ver`? And `tokens=*` instead of `tokens^=*` right?

Comment: @Compo: `%__AppDir__%\cmd.exe" /D /C ver` runs in cmd directly but returns error `The system cannot find the file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /C ver.` when running from batch file.

Comment: @jeb: Thank you for the pointer. Yes the problem only occurs when starting the cmd via the `AutoRun` registry key. Do you know how I can get around the problem and still be able to get result from `ver` in an auto run batch file?

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned in the comments beneath your question, the apparent freezing is caused by fact that you've setup that cmd statement to be executed through the cmd's `AutoRun` registry setting: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HKEY_CURRENT_USER]\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

When using `for /F` to capture the output of another command/program, an implicit instance of `cmd` will be invoked to execute the command/program referenced in the `for`'s IN clause.

When there is an entry in the cmd's `AutoRun` registry setting that implicit `cmd` instance will in turn execute the `AutoRun` commands, And in your case that `AutoRun` command will execute another instance of `cmd` through the `for /F` command. You see that where it is going: infinite chain of nested `cmd`s will be launched until it exhaust system resources.

To avoid trapping in the infinite loop, you need to guard the statement from executing more than once

Here is one method which is written as a batch file:

```
:: This batch file can be safely executed through cmd's Autorun

@echo off
if not defined WinVer (
    set "WinVer=AutorunGuard"
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=[" %%A in ('ver') do (
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=] " %%V in ("%%B") do set "WinVer=%%V"
    )
)
```

I've also extended the method of extracting windows version to include only the version number, not the whole version string which is return by `ver`
It can be used to extract version number for windows versions from Windows 2000 to Windows 10

If you don't want to use a batch file, and prefer to put the statement strait in to `AutoRun` registry setting, this one-liner can be used instead:

```
@if not defined WinVer set "WinVer=AutorunGuard" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=[" %A in ('ver') do @for /F "tokens=2 delims=] " %V in ("%B") do @set "WinVer=%V"
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid recursion and unexcpected FOR/F behaviour, you can use a guard in the AutoRun batch script (like the [variable based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58194737/463115) one shown by @sst).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=!cmdcmdline!"

if "!cmd!" == "!cmd:/=!" (
    REM *** Define doskey macros
    2>nul (
      doskey npp="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\notepad++\notepad++.exe" $*
    )

    endlocal

    REM *** Set additional variables

    REM *** Change to a default directory
    cd c:\temp
)
```

Comment: This approach is safer than the variable based one posted by me, as the variable could be defined with a fake value and bypass the script. However I think it should be safe to exclude only `/c`.  So with `/k` or `/v` switches the autorun remains functional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your batch file as **ver.bat**;
Rename it for example as **CMD_Version.bat**

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('ver') DO (SET var=%%i)
echo %var%
pause
```

Comment: The name of the file is not `ver.bat` though.

Comment: Even if the name is `ver.bat` or `ver.cmd` it still executes the internal `ver` command, as internal commands and have precedence over external ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the information from Win32_OperatingSystem using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```bat
@For /F "EOL=V" %%A In ('WMIC OS Get Version')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A")Do @Set "var=%%B"
```

or [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('"PowerShell (GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem).Version"')Do @Set "var=%%A"
```

You could also do the same using [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh), i.e. leveraging one of the [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) or [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) engines.

---

An alternative, though not as robust as using WMI, is to get the information from the registry.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
Set "KVal=\<CurrentBuildNumber\> \<CurrentVersion\> \<ProductName\> \<UBR\>"
For /F Tokens^=1-2* %%A In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%RKey%" 2^>NUL^|"%__AppDir__%findStr.exe" /I "%KVal%"^"'
)Do @If "%%A"=="UBR" (Set /A %%A=%%C)Else Set "%%A=%%C"
Echo(%ProductName% %CurrentVersion%.%CurrentBuildNumber%.%UBR%
Pause
```

Note: I do not think that `UBR` is a pre Windows 7 entry, so in those cases you'd simply have a trailing period in your output.

Comment: `for /f` implicitly invokes `cmd /c ....` without the `/d` switch. Anything you put inside the `for`'s IN clause will be nested inside it. So even using `cmd /d /c ...` does not solve the cmd `Aurorun` problem. Putting any of the solutions in the cmd `Autorun` leads to infinite chain of nested invocations.